Touch Controller Haptics Don't Work in Unity Scene?
I am creating a VR experiment in Unity using the Meta Quest 3 and touch controllers. Everything is working great except for one element - the haptic feedback for the controllers. Here is my current script:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScreenOverlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas overlayImage;
    public Haptic1 hapticScript; // Reference to the Haptic1 script
    private float hapticDuration = 0.5f;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Ensure the overlay image is initially disabled
        overlayImage.enabled = false;

        // Find and get the CartAppearance script
        hapticScript = Object.FindFirstObjectByType<Haptic1>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Detect index button press on the left controller and trigger the flash effect
        if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger, OVRInput.Controller.LTouch))
        {
            FlashScreen();

            StartCoroutine(TriggerHapticFeedback());
        }
    }

    private void FlashScreen()
    {
        // Enable the overlay image to simulate the flash effect
        overlayImage.enabled = true;

        // Delay for a short duration (e.g., 0.1 seconds)
        StartCoroutine(DisableOverlayAfterDelay(0.1f));
    }

    private IEnumerator DisableOverlayAfterDelay(float delay)
    {
        // Wait for the specified delay
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        // Disable the overlay image after the delay
        overlayImage.enabled = false;
    }
    private IEnumerator TriggerHapticFeedback()
    {
        OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(1, 1, OVRInput.Controller.LTouch);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(hapticDuration);
        OVRInput.SetControllerVibration(0, 0, OVRInput.Controller.LTouch);
    }
}


There is no haptic feedback when the index button on the left controller is pressed and I have no clue why?? I have the Meta all-in-one SDK package downloaded - and it works great for tracking etc - and this should also allow me to utilise haptics. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?
I have tried writing separate scripts and calling haptics from them to no avail. Nothing I have tried makes the controller vibrate or move in any way whatsoever
